# sphinx, rinohtype: Getting striped tables

Tags: python-3.x, python-sphinx, rinohtype

I am unable to understand how to get striped tables using stylesheets in rinohtype. For example, the below code generates a striped table when using rst2pdf

```
.. list-table:: Table Caption
    
    * - Header 1
      - Header 2
    * - Row 1
      - Row 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [default matcher](http://www.mos6581.org/rinohtype/master/stylesheets.html#default-matcher) defines the *table body cell background on even row* and *table body cell background on odd row* selectors. Try assigning styles to those in a custom style sheet, like this:

```ini
[table body cell background on even row]
fill_color = #00FF00

[table body cell background on odd row]
fill_color = #FF0000
```

To find out which style properties a particular selector accepts, click the associated style in the list of selectors in the manual section linked to above. See [matcher.py](https://github.com/brechtm/rinohtype/blob/804545998d4db3d606089bfe1754cd18ad21c85d/src/rinoh/stylesheets/matcher.py) to see the definition for these selectors.